# How to set a icon in the launcher for Scala IDE - Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scala-ide

I want to set the right icon of Scala IDE in the Ubuntu launcher,
because it appears the ? icon.

My version of Ubuntu is 16.04.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: See `~/.local/share/applications/` for examples and put one `xxx.desktop` for scala-IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need found *.desktop file for Scala IDE and insert line like:
Icon=path/to/icon

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, move to `/usr/share/applications/`

There, I have to create a `.desktop` file, with the next content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Scala         //you can choose whatever you want
Comment=Scala IDE
Exec=/path/to/the/executable
Icon=/path/to/the/photo.jpg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true`
```

First I used the file `icon.xpm`, 
but it didn't work.

I had to download a `.jpg` icon from Google Images.